# prepareForSegue: sender: not being called in app with a menu using SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, swrevealviewcontroller

I have an app with a sidebar menu using SWRevealViewController. I followed [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQtwIwAWoVChMItbKk4NusyAIVEVSICh1TFQGv&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D5SUV1YY2yxQ&usg=AFQjCNHCqCrfH824I2_Xrigi9DEEhIq0kQ&sig2=BvMXqSnPQ9agy2_4MVRWMw) tutorial on how to make it, but have a problem. I have many subviews of the first subview that has the `prepareForSegue: sender:` method. In my subclass view controller, I have the implementation:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
do Saving....
[super prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender];

}
```

The saving never gets called. I put an `NSLog()` statement and it was never executed. My layout is the same as the video tutorial (modified for my own app, different view controllers for each table cell). Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]; 

SecondViewController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController]; 

[navController setViewControllers: @[rootViewController] animated: YES];
```

It work for me

Or else follow this tutorial you will find solution.

[SWReavalview Controller](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/)

Comment: In which part of the SWRevealViewController.m do you place this code?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {


if([segue isKindOfClass:[SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController class] ]){

    UIViewController *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];

    UINavigationController *navCtrl = (UINavigationController *) self.revealViewController.frontViewController;

    [navCtrl setViewControllers:@[dvc] animated:NO];

    [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition:FrontViewPositionLeft animated:YES];
}
```